# mock object for flinks DataStream

Tags: scala, mockito, apache-flink, scalatest

Using Apache flink and scala with mockito.
Trying to get a string injected in a mock DataStream to test two test cases. I am not sure how to mock Flink's DataStream object with some data. Any ideas?

```scala
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar


class MockTest extends FunSuite with MockitoSugar {

  test ("Test DataStream with valid string") {
    var mockDataStream = mock[DataStream[String]]
    // inject "hello" to this datastream

    filterOutBlanks(mockDataStream)

    // verify mockDataStream is not empty
  }

  test ("Test DataStream with empty string") {
    var mockDataStream = mock[DataStream[String]]
    // inject "  " to this datastream

    filterOutBlank(mockDataStream)

    // verify mockDataStream is empty
  }


  def filterOutBlank(source: DataStream[String]): DataStream[String] = {
    source.filter(x => {
      StringUtils.isNotBlank(x)
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: add more details. what are you trying to achieve as your resultant?

Comment: I have updated the code with the intent

Comment: Why aren't you using StreamExecutionEnvironment#fromElements(myString)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mock `DataStream`. If you want to test the business logic that you wrote, you can simply unit test the functions that you implemented (like MapFunction, ReduceFunction etc.).

For other cases, you can test your computation by using ITCases. [Here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-scala/src/test/scala/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/scala/WindowReduceITCase.scala) you can find an example how to test your pipeline. You need to add the `flink-test-utils` module to your Maven dependencies.